# substitution to homogeneous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By making substitution  $y=zx^n$ choosing a convenient value of n  show that the following differential equations can be transformed
into equations with separable variables, and thereby solve this:
$dy/dx=\frac{1-xy^2}{2x^2y}$

My attempt:

$F=2x^2dy=(1-xy^2)dx$

$2x^2dy-(1-xy^2)dx=0$
Substitutions: $y=zx^n$ and $ dy=x^ndz$

$2x^{2+2n}zdz+(x^{2n+1}z^2-1)dx=0$

$F_{xy}=F_{yx}$

After taking derivative we get

$n=-1/2$

Which is the correct answer 
My question is that  $dy/dx=\frac{1-xy^2}{2x^2y}$ the -1 and 2 are just before $xy^2$ and $x^2y$ is n related to them I mean for every problem do I have to go through my way to get that or by dividing them can i get that? 
Because in the other problems of my book it is still the case.. Problems are

$y'=\frac{2+3xy^2}{4x^2y}$ $ n=3/4$

$y'=\frac{y-xy^2}{x+x^2y}$ $n=-1$

Answer (score 2):

It is not so simple. Just take any of these examples and multiply the right-hand side by a constant. The transformation will be the same. 
The good news is you don't have to do so many calculations:

Consider "Quasi-homogenity" (See for example the Arnol'd's *Ordinary Differential Equation* book). The next theorem will give you a hint on what to do:

**Theorem** A quasi-homogeneous equation $y'=F(x,y)$ with weight $deg x=\alpha, deg y=\beta$ can be reduced to an equation with separable variables by passing to the coordenates $(x,y^\alpha/x^\beta)$ in the domain $x>0$.

In the theorem the equation is quasi-homogeneous if and only if $F(e^{\alpha \xi}x,e^{\beta \xi}y)=e^{(\beta-\alpha) \xi}F(x,y)$. In polinomials you should only count degrees:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-homogeneous_polynomial