# Concern about the degree of rational functions that are Quasi-homogeneous in Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I came across an interesting set of problems as follows:
\begin{gather}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} =\dfrac{1-xy^2}{2x^2y} \tag{1}\label{1} \\
\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{2+3xy^2}{4x^2y} \tag{2}\label{2} \\
\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y-xy^2}{x+x^2y}. \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{gather}
We know these can be solved via Exact Equations and Integrating factors; however, the point of this exercise is to use the following substitution: $z=\dfrac{y}{x^n}$ where $n$ is any real number.

The difficulty I am facing is "how to determine the value of $n$ other than just guessing".
For instance, for \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}: $n=-\frac{1}{2}$ and for \eqref{3}: $n=-1$.
(Note for \eqref{2}, the textbook uses $n=\frac{3}{4}$, but when I tried $n=-\frac{1}{2}$, it worked just fine.)

Just to be clear, the chapter mainly discusses "Homogeneous Equations", but the last exercises invite us to try to extend this by using techniques that convert the differential equation into a separable equation (sometimes "homogeneous equation"), and this substitution indeed does that, but the value of $n$ is the "weird" part, as it seems determining the value of $n$ is by "guessing or trial and improvement".

Searching the internet, I deduced this substitution is related to Quasi-homogeneous equations.

For instance, [substitution to homogeneous equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1969837/substitution-to-homogeneous-equation#:%7E:text=Theorem%20A%20quasi%2Dhomogeneous%20equation,in%20the%20domain%20x%3E0.) asks the same questions as I stated above; however, I am having the same difficulty in determining the degree of $x$ and degree of $y$ in the theorem in the reply.

Here is the theorem for convenience:

Theorem: A quasi-homogeneous equation $y'=F(x,y)$
with weight $\deg x=\alpha$, $\deg y=\beta$
can be reduced to an equation with separable variables by passing to the coordinates $(x,y^\alpha/x^\beta)$
in the domain $x>0$.

In the theorem the equation is quasi-homogeneous if and only if $F(e^{\alpha\xi}x,e^{\beta\xi}y)=e^{(\beta-\alpha)}\xi F(x,y)$. In polynomials you should only count degrees; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-homogeneous_polynomial).

Ok, I am aware that the theorem is not meant for "introduction to DE", as it is found in Arnold's DE book. But, for polynomials, the only Issue I face now is how to determine $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Searching further on the internet, I found a more concrete way to understanding the "quasi-homogeneous equations" : [Solving a differential equation related to quasihomogeneous polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4392486/solving-a-differential-equation-related-to-quasihomogeneous-polynomials?noredirect=1&lq=1).

projectilemotion's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4392529) discusses two methods, the issue in the first method is what I initially have, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are called "weights" and the answer does not justify how to find them.
And for the second method discussed, it does not work for Equation \eqref{1}, listed above for example.
I.e., $\deg_x f = \operatorname{Max}(1,2) = 2 $ and $\deg_y f = \operatorname{Max}(2,1) = 2$.
Hence, the substitution should be $y=zx$; however, we know the substitution is $y=\sqrt{x}z$ and trying $y=zx$ does not work.

Maybe because issue in the method used to determine the degree, he said, by "convention."
However, I wonder if this convention works for DEs?

Now, how I solve these is as follows:
$$f(\lambda^\alpha x, \lambda^\beta y)=\lambda^{\beta - \alpha}f(x,y)$$
Which is the definition of quasi-homogeneous.
What I do is substitute these into the differential equation and by equating both sides I get for instance, $\alpha+2\beta=0$ , implying $\frac{\beta}{\alpha}=-\frac{1}{2}$, which is the correct substitution for \eqref{1}. But, this also assumes that the DE is Quasi-homogeneous, before knowing it.

Sorry for the very long post, but I was just trying to explain exactly where the "issue" lies, and that the previously asked questions regarding these topics did not clarify the degrees.
Note: these problems come from the second chapter (First Order Equations) in G. Simmons book: Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes; thus, for solving them, it does not require any knowledge of (very) "advanced" mathematics.

Thank you in advance.

Also asked by me on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454349/concern-about-the-degree-of-rational-functions-that-are-quasi-homogeneous-in-dif).

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. You have just recently cross-posted this to MathOverflow at [Concern about the degree of rational functions that are Quasi-homogeneous in Differential Equations](https://mathoverflow.net/q/454349/129887). As I've commented on your question there, this is generally discouraged. Nonetheless, if you do that, please at least include links between each post. Thus, for example, this will help to avoid duplication of effort between the members here and those on MathOverflow.

Comment: Oh, I apologize; I thought it is not against the rules. 
Added the link in the edit, and won't repeat the same mistake again. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome for the information. One other fairly important thing to note is that a question like yours appears to be a good match for this site, but perhaps not for MathOverflow as it's meant for current mathematical research type questions. Thus, you should only possibly post there, either just by itself or after a reasonable period of time here (note the one week is just what I read in a few places, with there actually not being any hard or fast rules, but I recommend you wait even somewhat longer, just to help make sure), *only* if you believe your question meets their requirements.

Comment: Oh, now I understand the difference between overflow and stack exchange; got it. Well, I did not find much references talking about quasi-homogeneous equations, maybe some research papers in linear algebra; so not sure if that meets the requirements on overflow. But, if it does not then admins are free to remove the question. 
I will follow your advice next time I post a question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\wt{wt}$To make \eqref{1} quasi-homogeneous, you need $1/(2x^2 y)$ and $(x y^2)/(2x^2 y)$ to have the same weight, so you need $\wt(x) + 2\wt(y) = 0$.  If you want the substitution $z = y^\alpha/x^\beta$ to be of the form $z = y/x^n$, then you should take $\alpha = \wt(x) = 1$, so that $n = \beta = \wt(y)$ is $-1/2$.  The same analysis applies for \eqref{2}.

To make \eqref{3} quasi-homogeneous, you need $x$ and $x^2 y$ to have the same weight, so you need $\wt(x) = 2\wt(x) + \wt(y)$; and then you need $y$ and $x y^2$ to have the same weight, so that you need $\wt(y) = \wt(x) + 2\wt(y)$.  The solutions of these two equations lie on the line $\wt(y) = -\wt(x)$, so that taking $\alpha = \wt(x) = 1$ gives $n = \beta = \wt(y) = -1$.

On further reading, I see that you already discussed this analysis for \eqref{1}, and rejected it.  Your ground made a lot of sense: this analysis seems to *assume* that the differential equation is quasi-homogeneous.  Note, however, that, in the way I have phrased it, I never say that the differential equation *is* quasi-homogeneous; I just speculate on what it would take to show that it is so.  If my goal were to prove that it was quasi-homogeneous, then I would have to go back and check that my idea works; but, if my goal is just to solve the differential equation, then no-one can stop me from making whatever substitution I like and seeing if it works.

That is, in this case we don't *have* to check the hypotheses of the theorem, since we aren't directly using its conclusion, only using it as inspiration for a method.  But it's a good idea to get in the habit of checking hypotheses anyway, so let's do that.  One easy way would have been for me to remember to say "the equation is quasi-homogeneous if and only if …" rather than "the equation is quasi-homogeneous only if …" up front.

But I didn't do that, so let's charge ahead.  In \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}, we have that $\wt(1/(2x^2 y))$ is $-(2\wt(x) + \wt(y)) = -(2(1) + (-1/2)) = -3/2$ and $\wt((x y^2/(2x^2 y))$ is $\wt(x y^2/(2x^2 y))$ is $(\wt(x) + 2\wt(y)) - (2\wt(x) + \wt(y)) = ((1) + 2(-1/2)) - (2(1) + (-1/2)) = -3/2$.  So we win, even if our idea to check this was motivated.  The checks for \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} are similar.

If your question was the more basic "OK, but how did I know to check for quasi-homogeneity in the first place?", then an entirely unsatisfying answer is "because you're doing practice problems involving quasi-homogeneity."  A slightly less unsatisfying answer is that the whole point of having a bag of differential-equations tricks is to be able to try various ones on various problems, without automatically knowing in advance which ones fit.  (A more satisfying answer would be: here's a way automatically to test a differential equation for quasi-homogeneity.  This amounts to the consistency of a certain system of linear equations, as above, but since the bare consistency is unlikely to be useful by itself, why not just try to solve the systems anyway, and either wind up with a solution or with the knowledge that you don't have a quasi-homogeneous equation after all?)

Comment: Hi LSpice, I really appreciate your answer; unfortunately can not upvote as still new. I got what you meant by "speculate on what it would take to show it is so." And that, at the introductory level, differential equations is about bag of tricks for solving various DEs. It really gave me a great insight that "you need 1/(2x^2y) and the other expression to have the same weight. However, I am having problem at the next line of your answer. wt(x) + 2 wt(y) = 0. Excuse my lack of knowledge, but how did we arrive at this? (Also is wt(x) is lambda^alpha?) . Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am guessing that the weight of "xy^2" should be zero, which is equivalent to saying w(x)+2w(y) = 0. So the "weight" can be thought of as an operator that separates and makes the power a "coefficient". so the weight of say, x^3y^8 would be 3w(x)+8w(y) and we will equate it with the weight of the other term. Did I understand it right? Thanks

Comment: Actually, having tried that on the three problems, it worked! It seems I overcomplicated the idea of finding the weights. Moreover, your method of using w in general seems much more efficient, than what I was using with lambdas. Thanks very much!! :)

Comment: @Nero, it sounds to me like you answered your own questions (which is the best way for MSE to proceed!).  Is that correct?  Although it's not the formal mathematical language that I would use, your [description](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4767038/concern-about-the-degree-of-rational-functions-that-are-quasi-homogeneous-in-dif/4767334#comment10124875_4767334) of what the weight function is doing seems right to me.  However, please be aware that I am not proposing any fundamentally different approach, just differently organising my way of thinking about the same approach.

Comment: Yes exactly what I was trying to say, much more organized way of using the given approach(definition). [What I was previously doing is using the definition (Literally substituting lambda^alpha x  into each and every x in the equation) and expanding everything, then factoring the top and bottom of the rational function, then reaching the same conclusion but in a mess]. Having learned how to use the weight function from your answer,  it did solve my main issue about three problems, I.e. finding "n" without guessing. Once again, thank you.